# Material icon loading issue

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, material-ui

In my recent Angular project I am using material icons by using google fonts as

[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons%7CMaterial+Icons+Outlined%7CMaterial+Icons+Two+Tone%7CMaterial+Icons+Round%7CMaterial+Icons+Sharp)

I have tried using all preload mechanism with  attribute.

When loading the Angular app, it takes while to display the icon. I have tried using self hosting also, but to no avail. It takes a while to render the actual icon.

Can any one suggest possible options to make the rendering of the material icon smoother/faster without having flickering effect to the users?

Comment: What is a _''a while"_ - are we talking about seconds here until the icons appear?

Comment: @iLuvLogix It's for 1 tp 2 seconds flickering and it's visible to users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use FontFace.load(). It will give you a Promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/load